# Constraint to tab bar bottom hiding paging control in tab controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a tab bar controller, on the second tab one of the objects I put in my view was a page control. I set a constraint so that it would appear right above the tab bar. When I look at it in the storyboard it looks exactly the way I want it to. When I open the app in the simulator and switch to that second tab, at first the page control is completely hidden, if I rotate the screen and then rotate back it appears and looks just fine.

The constraint in question is vertical space between the bottom layout guide.top and page control.bottom equal to 0.

[image: Constraints for paging control]
[image: Detail of constraint]
[image: Layout of paging control]

Comment: You should post code and if possible screen shots... How else can we see what your currently doing!

Comment: Make sure you set the proper constraints on the story board. Place a bottom constraint to the top of the tab bar or the bottom of the view but make sure you include the tab bar size.

Comment: Please change ur question title

Comment: Raheel, I changed the title, and added the screenshots. Douglas gave the correct answer already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, delete all constraints you have now.  Then add the following.  Height, width, TO BOTTOM OF VIEW, then center in container.  It should look like this..

[image: storyboard]

Rotation should be fine now, and you will see your page control.  I set it up the way you had it and was able to repeat what you saw.  Setting that constraint to the bottom of view helped.

Comment: Notice on the left my bottom constraint is 56.

Comment: I don't understand it. But it works! It seems like the big difference is the constraint being to the view instead of the bottom layout guide. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not a problem, I ran into the same thing not too long ago.